# Jersey app detect own port?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

Is there anyway for a Jersey server application to detect which port it is running on? Preferably *before* it receives any external requests.

It seems like there should be some sort of 'context' available but I'm drawing a blank.

TIA.

Comment: post your answer as a normal answer and then accept it. now your question violates the conventions of this site.